# Which timezone is used to determine what falls within a given day in Azure?

Tags: azure-cost-management

I created several Azure OpenAI resources in my Azure account. I deployed GPT models in each of the Azure OpenAI resources. I access them via the Azure OpenAI Playground.

I want to look at the cost incurred by the GPT models. I see I can view the cost per day (e.g.,  see the screenshot below showing the cost incurred by the GPT models on Aug. 5).

Which timezone is used to determine what falls within a given day?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTC time zone, according to [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/359567/cost-analysis-dashboard) by Microsoft Employee [SadiqhAhmed-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/na/?userid=a99787f3-7898-4128-9ac8-a27d38e96d95).

> Currently, all our cost data is emitted and stored in UTC time zone. We are still evaluating on our end how to move forward to enable switching from UTC to local. However, there is no defined ETA to share publicly.